# Find a corresponding orthonormal set

Tags: linear-algebra

I was able to show that the functions 1, cos(nx), sin(nx), n = 1,2,3,... form an orthogonal set for the inner product $$(f,g)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\overline {g(x)}dx$$ on the space of continuous functions.  What I am having trouble with is finding the orthonormal set.

For starters, what is the difference between the orthonormal set and the orthogonal set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By orthonormal set we mean a set of vectors which are *unit* i.e. with norm equal $1$ and the set is orthogonal that's the vectors are $2$ by $2$ orthogonal. In your case you should divide every vector by its norm to form an orthonormal set.

Comment: So just divide by the norm?  $(1,\frac{cosnx}{\sqrt{cos(nx)^2}},\frac{sinnx}{\sqrt{sin(nx)^2}})$?  Is it really that simple?

Comment: No the norm of $\cos (nx)$ for example is
$$(\cos(nx),\cos(nx))^{1/2}=\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2(nx)dx}$$

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought that $\parallel x\parallel = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2}$

Comment: What you showed is the norm of a vector in $\Bbb C^n$ using the inner product
$$(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\overline{y_k}$$
but in the given question your vector space is the space of continuous functions and the inner product is mentioned  in your question so they are totally different.

Comment: Ah, $\parallel x\parallel = \sqrt{x \cdot x}$.  So where does the integral come from?

Comment: The integral comes from the inner product in your question: it's defined by an integral. You see it ?

Comment: Yeah.  That makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.